# Nested radical and rationality

Tags: irrational-numbers, nested-radicals

I did not found it on the forum so :
$$S=\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{2^2}\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{2^3}\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{2^4}\sqrt{\cdots}}}}}=1.25$$

I try to denested the radical but I'm really stuck to get wich follows .
Maybe a generalization could be give the result.

Furhtermore I have a question is 2 the only number such that :

$$\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{k}\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{k^2}\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{k^3}\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{k^4}\sqrt{\cdots}}}}}$$

is rational ?

Where $k\geq 2$ is a natural number

Thanks a lot for your answer and your time .

Comment: I can see this generalization only:
$$\sqrt{1+x\sqrt{1+\frac{x}{2}\sqrt{1+\frac{x}{2^2}\sqrt{1+\frac{x}{2^3}\sqrt{\cdots}}}}}=1 + \dfrac{x}{2}.$$

Comment: Wonder if we could generalise it for $x/n$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the unique power series in $\,t\,$ that satisfies
$$ f(t,q) = \sqrt{1 + tf(t\,q,q)}. \tag{1} $$
We can express it as a continued square root
$$ f(t,q) = \sqrt{1 + t\sqrt{1 + t\,q\sqrt{1 +
t\,q^2 \cdots}}}. \tag{2} $$
The first few terms are
$$ f(t,q) \!=\! 1 \!+\! (1/2)\,t^2 \!+\!
 (-1/8\!+\!1/4q)\,t^3 \!+\! \\
(1/16q\!-\!1/8q\!-\!1/16q^2\!+\!1/8q^3)\,t^4
 \!+ \cdots .\tag{3} $$
A special case closed form formula is
$$ f(1/2^n,1/2)=1+2^{-(n+1)}, \tag{4} $$
proven by induction using equation $(1)$ and the
identity $$(1 + r/2) = \sqrt{1 + r(1 + r/4)}\;\;
\text{ where } \;\; r = 2^{-n}. \tag{5} $$
The question asked about
$\,f(\frac12,\frac12) = \frac54\,$ using equation $(4)$
with $\,n=1.$

NOTE: In equation $(2)$ the continued square root is
the limit of a sequence
$$ x,\; \sqrt{1\!+\!t\,x},\;
 \sqrt{1\!+\!t\sqrt{1\!+\!t\,q\,x}},\;
 \sqrt{1\!+\!t\sqrt{1\!+\!t\,q\sqrt{1\!+\!t\,q^2x}}},\;\cdots $$
which converges at least for
non-negative $\,t,q,x\,$ which needs some kind
of proof in general.

Comment: Do we have to worry about convergence in equation (2) (since we have infinitely many terms)?

Comment: Well by Vigaraghavan's take on the Herschfeld's theorem, we have, $\sqrt{a_0+\sqrt{a_1+\sqrt{a_2+...}}}$ converges if and only if $$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\log{a_n}}{2^n}<\infty$$ Then using this to check out the convergence for Eq $2$, we get the radical converges iff, $$2(\log(t)+\log(q))<\infty$$$$=\log(tq)<\infty$$. So as long as $q,t$ are both finite quantities, the radical will surely converge.

Comment: @rzkrd Thanks for that helpful comment! I knew that there was a theorem about continued square roots such as this.