# Complex nested radicals ${\Re}\Big(\sqrt{1+\frac{i}{2}\sqrt{1+\frac{i}{2^2}\sqrt{1+\frac{i}{2^3}\sqrt{1+\frac{i}{2^4}\sqrt{\cdots}}}}}\Big)=1$

Tags: complex-numbers, power-series, closed-form, nested-radicals

A Last question on nested radicals but this time with complex value :

$${\Re}\Big(\sqrt{1+\frac{i}{2}\sqrt{1+\frac{i}{2^2}\sqrt{1+\frac{i}{2^3}\sqrt{1+\frac{i}{2^4}\sqrt{\cdots}}}}}\Big)=1$$

I have tried to use power series like in the [answer of Somos](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3500644/nested-radical-and-rationality) but I fail.

Furthermore we have the beautiful relation 
  $$S={\Re}\Big(\sqrt{1+\frac{i}{2}\sqrt{1+\frac{i}{2^2}\sqrt{1+\frac{i}{2^3}\sqrt{1+\frac{i}{2^4}\sqrt{\cdots}}}}}\Big)+{\Im}\Big(\sqrt{1+\frac{i}{2}\sqrt{1+\frac{i}{2^2}\sqrt{1+\frac{i}{2^3}\sqrt{1+\frac{i}{2^4}\sqrt{\cdots}}}}}\Big)=\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{2^2}\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{2^3}\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{2^4}\sqrt{\cdots}}}}}=1.25$$
Furthermore I think it's good to know what happend in the case of complex number with the Herschfeld's theorem .If somebody have some paper on this it would be cool .

My question :How solve it ?

Thanks in advance .

Comment: The square root is double-valued on the complex plane; which value do you choose for each square root? Or do you claim that the result is independent of the choices?

Comment: @Servaes All radicands are "near $1$", so we want the same for the square roots

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the referenced answer by *Somos*, you want (the real part of) $f(\frac i2,\frac12)$. But if $t\mapsto f(t,\frac12)$ is a power series that converged in a neighbourhood of $0$ and that equals $1+\frac t2$ for infinitely many values of $t$ (see equation  $(4)$ in the referenced answer) accumulating at $0$, then by the identitiy theorem, $f(t,\frac12)=1+\frac t2$ holds for all $t$ (where we have convergence). Consequently,
$$ \Re\left(f(\tfrac i2,\tfrac12)\right)=\Re(1+\tfrac i4)=1.$$

Comment: Oh I see now ! Thanks !