# Almost integer with nested radicals and power tower .

Tags: power-series, nested-radicals, constants, power-towers

playing with power tower and nested radicals I get :

Prove that

> > Let $a_1=\sqrt{2}$ ,$a_2=\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}}$,$a_3=\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}}}$,$a_4=\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}}}}$ and $a_5=\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}}}}}$ then we have :
> >     $$\sqrt{1+a_1\sqrt{1+a_2\sqrt{1+a_3\sqrt{1+a_4\sqrt{1+a_5}}}}}<2$$

You can check the value [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt%281%2Bsqrt%282%29*sqrt%281%2Bsqrt%282%29%5Esqrt%282%29sqrt%281%2Bsqrt%282%29%5Esqrt%282%29%5Esqrt%282%29sqrt%281%2Bsqrt%282%29%5Esqrt%282%29%5Esqrt%282%29%5Esqrt%282%29sqrt%281%2Bsqrt%282%29%5Esqrt%282%29%5Esqrt%282%29%5Esqrt%282%29%5Esqrt%282%29%29%29%29%29%29). This is an [almost integer](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/AlmostInteger.html) .

I have tried to find a recursion formula without success .If we continue like this we get a limit by the [Herschfeld's theorem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HerschfeldsConvergenceTheorem.html) . Moreover I have tried brut force but it's not nice the power series by example the power series of $f(x)=\sqrt{x}^{\sqrt{x}}$ at $x=2$.And finally I have tried to apply something near to the [Somos answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3500644/nested-radical-and-rationality) without success again .

If you have nice idea to prove it .

Thanks a lot for all your contributions !